# Количество заказанного товара

Tags: php

Сейчас, как Вы наверное уже знаете, делаю интернет-магазин. Так вот происходят постоянно чудеса... Сейчас попробую объяснить, что не так! Я вывожу товары, которые добавил пользователь в корзину, рядом стоимость, количество и сумму. Так вот количество появляется правильное, затем сразу же, еще при загрузке меняется на единицы или на числа "13", но при этом сумма остается правильной. Что делать в такой ситуации???

[image: Первый скриншот]
[image: Второй скриншот]

```
function view_basket($id){
    // Функция выводит все товары, которые находятся в корзине
        $total = 0;
        $query = "SELECT b.id as basket_id,  b.customer, b.quantity as basket_quantity, b.ip, b.time ,
                    p.id as product_id, p.title as product_title, price as product_price, 
                    p.images as product_image, p.category as product_category
                    FROM basket b 
                    INNER JOIN products p ON (p.id = b.product_id)
                    WHERE b.customer='".session_id()."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "<div class=\"cart\">
                <form action=\"basket.php\" id=\"basket\" method=\"post\">
                    <h2>Товары в Вашей корзине</h2>
                    <div id=\"buttons\" align=\"right\"><button class=\"btn\" id=\"continue\">Продолжить покупки</button><a href=\"basket.php#makeorder\" class=\"btn btn-success\">Оформить заказ</a></div>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id = mysql_real_escape_string($row['product_id']);
            //echo "$id";
            $text = mysql_real_escape_string($row['product_title']);
            //echo "$text";
            $price = mysql_real_escape_string($row['product_price']);
            //echo "$price";
            $images = mysql_real_escape_string($row['product_image']);
            $category = mysql_real_escape_string($row['product_category']);
            $quantity = mysql_real_escape_string($row['basket_quantity']);
            echo "$quantity";
            $summ = $price * $quantity; // Сумма
            $total = $total + $summ; // Итого

            if (isset($_GET['currency'])) {
                $currency = (string)$_GET['currency'];

            }

            // Разорабться почему меняются значения количества товара сами по себе???

            if ($currency == "USD") {
                $query = "SELECT rate FROM currency WHERE title='$currency'";
                $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                $r = mysql_fetch_array($res);
                $rate = (float)$r['rate'];
                $summ = ($price * $quantity)/$rate; // Сумма в USD
                $price = round((float)$price/$rate, 2);
                $summ = round((float)$summ, 2);
                $total = ($total + $summ)/$rate; // Итого
                $total = round((float)$total, 2);
                $price_string = "<span class=\"price\" data-price=\"$price\">\$ $price</span>";
                $summ_string = "<span class=\"summ\">\$ $summ</span>";
                $total_string = "<span class=\"summ price\">\$ $total</span>";
            }

            if ($currency == "UAH") {
                $price_string = "<span class=\"price\" data-price=\"$price\">$price грн.</span>";
                $summ_string = "<span class=\"summ\">$summ грн.</span>";
                $total_string = "<span class=\"summ price\">$total грн.</span>";
            }

            if(empty($currency)){
                $price_string = "<span class=\"price\" data-price=\"$price\">$price грн.</span>";
                $summ_string = "<span class=\"summ\">$summ грн.</span>";
                $total_string = "<span class=\"summ price\">$total грн.</span>";
            }

            echo "<a href=\"../img/$images\" class=\"fancybox\"><img src=\"../img/$images\" alt=\"$text\" width=\"150\" border=\"0\"></a>
                    <span><a href=\"single.php?id=$id&catid=$category\">$text</a></span>
                    <div class=\"price\" style=\"float:right;\">$price_string<span style=\"color:#7F888C\"> × </span><input class=\"input-qty\" name=\"\" type=\"text\" value=\"$quantity\"><span style=\"color:#7F888C\"> шт. </span>$summ_string</div>
                    <div align=\"right\"><i class=\"icon-trash\"></i><a class=\"currency\" href=\"delete-from-basket.php?id=$id\">удалить</a></div>";
        }
        echo "</form><div class=\"total\"><i class=\"icon-print\"></i><a class=\"print\" href=\"\">Распечатать</a><div style=\"float:right;\"><span class=\"price\" style=\"color:#7F888C\">Итого: </span>$total_string</div></div>
            </div>";
    }
```

Comment: Если "Слишком спорно", то могу выложить код функции, которая делает вывод товаров в корзине??!!

Comment: спорность состоит в том что а) ваш вопрос в стиле газеты "Жизнь" - очень уж похоже на дешевую попытку привлечь внимание броским заголовком б) программировать по скриншотам - занятие довольно бесполезное, так что да, имело бы смысл выложить код, а не скриншоты

Если вам помогли исходя даже из той скудной  противоречивой информации, что вы предоставили - я искренне за вас рад, тем не менее при составлении вопросов старайтесь избегать неопределенных формулировок и бульварных заголовков (все же каким бы php ни был языком, вероятность его схождения с ума куда ниже, чем аналогичная для программиста

Comment: Обновил. Выложил код функции, которая выводит корзину товаров. С формулировками буду по мягче в следующий раз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, проблема в javascript, в функции, которая пересчитывает стоимость по введенному количеству. PHP не может менять HTMl после вывода без дополнительных извращений.

Comment: Полностью с Вами согласен, сам был обескуражен подобным поведением кода. Действительно, я параллельно, на JS, веду подсчет общей суммы заказа, но никуда ничего не вывожу...

Comment: Понимаете, дело в том, что функция, которая пересчитывает стоимость по введенному количеству еще не реализована...

Comment: Тогда давайте код вывода и html шаблон

Comment: Обновил. Выложил код функции, которая выводит корзину товаров.

Comment: в коде криминала не обнаружил, с вероятностью в 99% говорю, что висит javascript, который и меняет значения кол-ва.